# Show x-ticks on all subplots and unique y label

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, subplot

I am plotting two subplots that share the same x-axis but when I plot I only see the x-axis ticks on the second subplot. How can I make the x-ticks visible on both subplots?

Also I would like to set y-labels for both subplots but only the second is visible. Can you please help in displaying the y-label on both subplots?

Below is my reproducible code.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import pandas as pd
desired_width = 1500
pd.set_option('display.width', desired_width)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame([{'DATETIME': '2017-09-29 01:00,', 'Population': 1000, 'Temp': 90, 'State': 'California'},
                   {'DATETIME': '2017-09-29 01:00,', 'Population': 2000, 'Temp': 70, 'State': 'Illinois'},
                   {'DATETIME': '2017-09-29 01:00,', 'Population': 3000, 'Temp': 50, 'State': 'Georgia'},
                   {'DATETIME': '2017-09-29 02:00,', 'Population': 2000, 'Temp': 40, 'State': 'California'},
                   {'DATETIME': '2017-09-29 02:00,', 'Population': 6000, 'Temp': 20, 'State': 'Illinois'},
                   {'DATETIME': '2017-09-29 02:00,', 'Population': 4000, 'Temp': 30, 'State': 'Georgia'},
                   {'DATETIME': '2017-09-29 03:00,', 'Population': 3000, 'Temp': 40, 'State': 'California'},
                   {'DATETIME': '2017-09-29 03:00,', 'Population': 4000, 'Temp': 60, 'State': 'Illinois'},
                   {'DATETIME': '2017-09-29 03:00,', 'Population': 2000, 'Temp': 80, 'State': 'Georgia'}])

df.index = df['DATETIME']
df.index = (pd.to_datetime(df.index)).strftime("%m/%d %H:00")

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1, sharex=True)

df.groupby('State')['Population'].plot(kind='line', linestyle='--', alpha=0.5, marker='o', legend=True, ax=axes[0])
plt.ylabel('Pop')
df.groupby('State')['Temp'].plot(kind='line', linestyle='--', alpha=0.5, marker='o', legend=True, ax=axes[1])
plt.ylabel('Temp')
plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='both', labelsize=7)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Current Chart Output:

[image]

Comment: Removing sharex=True displays on both subplots but does not show properly formatted on the first plot. I'd like to display the x-axis formatted using the specified parameters on all subplots. I would also like to have unique y labels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of things you can do. Either remove `sharex = True`. Or, if you want to use that,  `sharex` sets the x ticks to not be visible i.e. `set_visible(False)`. Therefore, you can set them to `True` to stop this.

In order to have the subplots formatted the same, you need to set the tick params for each subplot by using `axes[0].tick_params(axis='both', which='both', labelsize=7)` for both subplots (i.e. repeat for `axes[1]`)

Note, personally I prefer to use matpotlib object oriented API i.e using `ax.set_ylabel()` rather than `plt.ylabel()` as I think it gives more control over which subplots and axes you are using. Therefore I have slightly modified your code in that regards too

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'DATETIME': '2017-09-29 01:00,', 'Population': 1000, 'Temp': 90, 'State': 'California'},
                   {'DATETIME': '2017-09-29 01:00,', 'Population': 2000, 'Temp': 70, 'State': 'Illinois'},
                   {'DATETIME': '2017-09-29 01:00,', 'Population': 3000, 'Temp': 50, 'State': 'Georgia'},
                   {'DATETIME': '2017-09-29 02:00,', 'Population': 2000, 'Temp': 40, 'State': 'California'},
                   {'DATETIME': '2017-09-29 02:00,', 'Population': 6000, 'Temp': 20, 'State': 'Illinois'},
                   {'DATETIME': '2017-09-29 02:00,', 'Population': 4000, 'Temp': 30, 'State': 'Georgia'},
                   {'DATETIME': '2017-09-29 03:00,', 'Population': 3000, 'Temp': 40, 'State': 'California'},
                   {'DATETIME': '2017-09-29 03:00,', 'Population': 4000, 'Temp': 60, 'State': 'Illinois'},
                   {'DATETIME': '2017-09-29 03:00,', 'Population': 2000, 'Temp': 80, 'State': 'Georgia'}])

df.index = df['DATETIME']
df.index = (pd.to_datetime(df.index)).strftime("%m/%d %H:00")

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1, sharex=True)

df.groupby('State')['Population'].plot(kind='line', linestyle='--', alpha=0.5, marker='o', legend=True, ax=axes[0])
axes[0].set_ylabel('Pop')
df.groupby('State')['Temp'].plot(kind='line', linestyle='--', alpha=0.5, marker='o', legend=True, ax=axes[1])
axes[1].set_ylabel('Temp')

# Set the formatting the same for both subplots
axes[0].tick_params(axis='both', which='both', labelsize=7)
axes[1].tick_params(axis='both', which='both', labelsize=7)

# set ticks visible, if using sharex = True. Not needed otherwise
for tick in axes[0].get_xticklabels():
    tick.set_visible(True)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Which gives:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This precisely accomplished what I was looking for. Can I ask one follow up? For a larger dataset I was setting `plt.xticks(np.arange(len(df) / df['State'].nunique()), df.index)` so that all xticks were displayed. Can I also do this for both subplots?

Comment: It doesn't work in Matplotlib 3.3.2 anymore.

Answer (score 12):

As other answers have mentioned, to get the `ylabel` showing up on both subplots, you can use the object-oriented interface here `axes[0].set_ylabel` and `axes[1].set_ylabel`.

You should also use `.tick_params` on both axes to get the same size tick labels, etc. for both subplots

And finally, to get the tick labels to show up on the first subplot, as an alternative to looping over all the ticks and having to set them to be visible, you can achieve the same thing by giving just one more option  `tick_params`: `labelbottom=True`.

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1, sharex=True)

df.groupby('State')['Population'].plot(kind='line', linestyle='--', alpha=0.5, marker='o', legend=True, ax=axes[0])
axes[0].set_ylabel('Pop')
df.groupby('State')['Temp'].plot(kind='line', linestyle='--', alpha=0.5, marker='o', legend=True, ax=axes[1])
axes[1].set_ylabel('Temp')
axes[0].tick_params(axis='both', which='both', labelsize=7, labelbottom=True)
axes[1].tick_params(axis='both', which='both', labelsize=7)
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, I did not know about that!

Comment: @DavidG: You are basically just undoing what `matplotlib` does under the hood when you set `sharex`, since it just sets `labelbottom=False` for all subplots except the bottom one

Comment: `labelbottom=True` doesn't work for me(

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the first question, I'd advise against that not to clutter the plot with extra ink.

Now, onto the y labels. you have to use the axes you get from `plt.subplots` replacing

`plt.ylabel('Pop')` by `axes[0].set_ylabel('Pop')`
and
`plt.ylabel('Pop')` by `axes[1].set_ylabel('Temp')`

Answer (score 0):

Remove `sharex=True` from `fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1, sharex=True)` to have separate x-axis.

For ylabels

```
axes[0].set_ylabel('Pop')
axes[1].set_ylabel('Temp')
```